# Orderby complex type using OData

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am starting to use OData in my MVC4 application and the problem that I am having, is that I cannot perform any sort or filter operations on my IQueryable because I am using complex objects. Below is a simple example of something I am trying to accomplish:

My API Controller is attempting to return a collection of MyObjects as IQueryable.

```
public IQueryable Get()
{
    List<MyObject> myObjects = GetMyObjects();
    return myObjects.AsQueryable() ;
}
```

Each MyObject contains an InnerObject that has the properties I want to sort and/or filter on.

```
public class MyObject
{
    [Key]
    public MyInnerObject innerObject{ get; set; }

    public MyObject(Dictionary<string, object> value)
    {
        innerObject= new MyInnerObject(){
            item = value["item"].ToString(),
            itmdesc = value["itmdesc"].ToString()
        };
    }
}

public class MyInnerObject
{
    public string item { get; set; }
    public string itmdesc { get; set; }
}
```

I can successfully execute the top commands through the url

```
localhost:5050/Test/Get?$top=10
```

But I really want to be able to sort my results using

```
localhost:5050/Test/Get?$top=10&$orderby=innerObject.item
```

I have tried

```
localhost:5050/Test/Get?$top=10&$orderby=innerObject.item
localhost:5050/Test/Get?$top=10&$orderby=innerObject/item
localhost:5050/Test/Get?$top=10&$orderby=item
```

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

I should mention that it works if I put the item and itmdesc properties within MyObject, but for my purposes (this is just a minified version of my complex entities), they will need to be wrapped in a complex type.

In my Api controller, I have also tried IQueryable< MyObject> but that doesnt make a difference

Answer (score 4):

In general, OData as a protocol allows the second thing you tried (`localhost:5050/Test/Get?$top=10&$orderby=innerObject/item`). It is likely that this is a temporary limitation of the Web API implementation of OData (assuming that's what you're using based on the rest of your environment and the returning of IQueryable).

Comment: Yea, I just don't understand. $filter works when I add single quotes around the object name. Tried that as well with orderby and...nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Aspnet Web API OData doesn't support ordering by nested properties or expressions. There is an [issue](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/791) open on codeplex for supporting ordering by nested properties.

However if you are slightly adventurous you can use ODataQueryOptions to model bind the individual odata query options and then translate $orderby AST to a linq expression and apply it manually to your IQueryable.

Comment: Is this still a thing? The page at the link implies that the request was closed and ordering by nested properties should be done on the client. Not much help for server side paging scenarios...